# shift values in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, spyder

I try to shift values in a DataFrame. I am working with Spyder 5.0.0.

I use `numpy.roll` to shift the `origin_df.values` and it works:

```
shifted = np.roll(origin_df.values, shift=4)
shifted_df = pd.DataFrame(shifted)
```

However, when I try to incorporate this into a function:

```
def shift_df(df, steps):
    shifted = np.roll(df.values, steps)
    shifted_df = pd.DataFrame(shifted)
    shifted_df.index = df.index
    return shifted_df
```

and call the function:

```
shifted_df = shift_df(origin_df, 4)
```

Spyder gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: _roll_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'shift'
```

[image]

Even more strange:

***EXACTLY the same*** works in a jupyter notebook as expected:

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: can you share the full traceback of the error you are getting in Spyder?

Comment: yes, just a moment

Comment: Strange indeed, something is off with Spyder perhaps.. Did you restart the kernel `:)`?

Comment: I have restarted the kernel and it worked! :) how strange ist this??

Comment: it's basically ecaxtly the same, I just called it `shift_df` in the example to point out, I am working with DataFrames ;)

Comment: I really don't know why the error occured in the first place, Spyder can be "interesting" sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED by restarting the kernel ... :D